# SO broke a working URL by mapping parentheses () to %28%29

Tags: bug, markdown, hyperlinks

I updated an answer to [How to make a Perl regex and references part of the matching string in the regex](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20384046/15168) and added a URL x-ref to the section of the Perl manual.

The URL works when it is spelled:

```
http://perldoc.perl.org/perlre.html#(%3f%3f%7b-code-%7d)
```

It does not work when spelled:

```
http://perldoc.perl.org/perlre.html#%28%3f%3f%7b-code-%7d%29
```

When I entered it, I included the parentheses; SO replaced parentheses with `%28` and `%29`. I'm not happy about that since it has broken a working URL (though I'm not entirely clear why it doesn't work as mapped).

---

#### Chrome vs Firefox (and the rest)?

In the light of the comments that "it works for me", I observe that I'm using Chrome 32.0.1700.41 beta on Mac OS X 10.9 Mavericks, and that did not jump to the correct section with the `%28...%29` URL.  I also get the same not-working effect with Chrome 31.0.1650.57 on an Ubuntu 12.04 derivative system.  The problem is probably in Chrome, therefore.  When I try Firefox 25.0.1 on Mac OS X, it works fine with the `%28...%29` URL; so does the the same version number of Firefox on the Ubuntu system.  I'll report an issue to Chrome developers.

The residual question is whether SO should adapt to a Chrome defect.

Comment: The link you edited into the post works for me.

Comment: Works for me as well.

Comment: Interesting: I'm using Chrome '32.0.1700.41 beta' on Mac OS X 10.9 Mavericks, and that did not jump to the correct section with the `%28...%29` version.  I also get the same not-working effect with Chrome 31.0.1650.57 on an Ubuntu 12.04 derivative system.  The problem may be Chrome, then; Firefox 25.0.1 on Mac OS X works fine with the `%28...%29` version; so does the the same version number on the Ubuntu system.  I'll report an issue to Chrome developers.

Comment: 8+ years later, with Chrome 114 on macOS Montery 12.6.7, the notation works with the `%28%29` escapes.  It has probably worked for many years.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem appears to have been in Chrome; other browsers have no problem.  There is a minor breakage on SO for a fairly widely used browser.

A month later, Chrome 31.0.1650.53 for Mac OS X 10.9.1 still does not work correctly.